# Story about magic/programming with some Greek mythology

Tags: story-identification

In this story magic is done by writing command-line sort of programs.  In the story the main guy ends up using some magic and ends up making his grandmother or something mad and ends up in hiding.  The whole story ends up with their “familiars”, constructs or AI's that they have created, kinda rebelling.  The main character's name was something like Raven.  There are a couple of characters that are semi-related to some greek mythology gods, but i can't think of which.

Oh, the main character and his family *are* gods, or something like that, and that's why they can do magic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the book you're looking to identify is [WebMage](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441014259) by [Kelly McCullough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_McCullough) and the character you're referring to is *Ravirn*.

Summary from [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/975638.WebMage):

> Ravirn is not your average computer geek. A child of the Fates—literally—he’s a hacker extraordinaire who can zero in on the fatal flaw in any program. Now that twenty-first-century magic has gone digital that makes him a very talented sorcerer. But a world of problems is about to be downloaded on Ravirn—who’s just trying to pass his college midterms.Great Aunt Atropos, one of the three Fates, decides that humans having free will is really overrated and plans to rid herself of the annoyance—by coding a spell into the Fate Core, the server that rules destiny. As a hacker, Ravirn is a big believer in free will, and when he not only refuses to debug her spell but actively opposes her, all hell breaks loose.

Comment: i love the internet!